# Discovery in c#

Tags: c#, .net, device-discovery

I've to implement some discovery for an internal solution.

We have two kind of software:

- *Server*: They manage a lot of hardware devices and can give access to some data (.Net remoting)
- *Client*: They can display data of one or several Server(graphs, stats, ...)

Currently we are setting the IP by hand on the client.

We would like to implement a *discovery*.

We have the following requirement:

- It has to be usable in c#
- When a server is up, it must be displayed as available very fastly
- Same when it shut down
- If the server doesn't stops in a clean way, we can have a way to detect it(no need to be very fast, can be done every 10-15min).
- It can give me some information(Server version, port to use, ...)
- We have client computer with multiple network cards, we must discover server on each cards

Do you have a protocol, a library, ... to advice?

We tried UPnP, but seems there is no good Server+client implementation in **c#** that meet our requirement

Comment: [WCF, maybe particularly Peer Channels et al.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb756931.aspx) could be of interest.

Comment: What's wrong with periodic sending of UDP-packets?

Comment: You could roll your own lightweight solution by sending/receiving [multicast UDP packets](http://www.jarloo.com/c-udp-multicasting-tutorial/), or go for [WCF Discovery](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd456782(v=vs.100).aspx).

Comment: @GrantThomas: I don't know, I was thinking that it wasn't making a lot of sense to use WCF discovery if we don't use WCF services

Comment: @Dennis: Periodic packet must be very close(to have reactivity) and this will be very network consuming

Comment: @KristianHellang: I like your first link, I'm trying to implement a small "UdpNode" that can receive and send packets. In the interval, you should give this in answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use UDP broadcasts from the discovering app (client):

```
int broadcastPort = //something
byte[] msg = //something

//Cycle this for all IP adresses
IPAddress broadcastIp = //Broadcast address for this net
IPEndPoint destinationEndpoint = new IPEndPoint(broadcastIp, broadcastPort);
Socket sock = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Dgram, ProtocolType.Udp);
sock.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.Socket, SocketOptionName.Broadcast, 1);
sock.SendTo(msg, broadcastEndpoint);
```

And have the discovered app (Server) answer, to receive the answer use `UdpClient.Receive()`, which gives you the IP of the answering station.

Comment: What is the main difference between using the UdpClient to send the message and using this socket?